# TestCase not found:constructor Object(java.lang.String) not found in class java.lang.Object

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I'm puzzled by this error

```
Error(4,8): TestCase not found
Error(11,14): constructor Object(java.lang.String) not found in class java.lang.Object
```

Any ideas?

[image: Error Screenshot]

```
package smsgateway;

import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class GlobalSMSProTest extends junit.framework.TestCase{

    private GlobalSMSPro myGlobalSMSPro;

    public GlobalSMSProTest(java.lang.String name){
        super(name);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        ServiceFactory factory = ServiceFactory.newInstance();
        myGlobalSMSPro = (smsgateway.GlobalSMSPro)factory.loadService(smsgateway.GlobalSMSPro.class);
    }

    protected void tearDown(){
        myGlobalSMSPro = null;
    }

    public void testGlobalSMSProSoapsendMessage() throws java.lang.Exception {
        smsgateway.GlobalSMSProSoap port = myGlobalSMSPro.getGlobalSMSProSoap();
        java.lang.String toNumber = null;
        java.lang.String fromName = null;
        java.lang.String messageText = null;
        java.lang.String optionalTextFormat = null;
        sms.com.strikeiron.ws.LicenseInfo licenseInfo = null;
        smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder subscriptionInfo = new  smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder();
        subscriptionInfo.value = null;
        port.sendMessage(toNumber, fromName, messageText, optionalTextFormat, licenseInfo, subscriptionInfo);
    }

    public void testGlobalSMSProSoapsendMessagesBulk() throws java.lang.Exception {
        smsgateway.GlobalSMSProSoap port = myGlobalSMSPro.getGlobalSMSProSoap();
        java.lang.String[] toNumbers = null;
        java.lang.String fromName = null;
        java.lang.String messageText = null;
        java.lang.String optionalTextFormat = null;
        sms.com.strikeiron.ws.LicenseInfo licenseInfo = null;
        smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder subscriptionInfo = new  smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder();
        subscriptionInfo.value = null;
        port.sendMessagesBulk(toNumbers, fromName, messageText, optionalTextFormat, licenseInfo, subscriptionInfo);
    }

    public void testGlobalSMSProSoaptrackMessage() throws java.lang.Exception {
        smsgateway.GlobalSMSProSoap port = myGlobalSMSPro.getGlobalSMSProSoap();
        java.lang.String trackingTicket = null;
        sms.com.strikeiron.ws.LicenseInfo licenseInfo = null;
        smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder subscriptionInfo = new  smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder();
        subscriptionInfo.value = null;
        port.trackMessage(trackingTicket, licenseInfo, subscriptionInfo);
    }

    public void testGlobalSMSProSoaptrackMessagesBulk() throws java.lang.Exception {
        smsgateway.GlobalSMSProSoap port = myGlobalSMSPro.getGlobalSMSProSoap();
        java.lang.String[] trackingTickets = null;
        sms.com.strikeiron.ws.LicenseInfo licenseInfo = null;
        smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder subscriptionInfo = new  smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder();
        subscriptionInfo.value = null;
        port.trackMessagesBulk(trackingTickets, licenseInfo, subscriptionInfo);
    }

    public void testGlobalSMSProSoapgetStatusCodesForMethod() throws java.lang.Exception {
        smsgateway.GlobalSMSProSoap port = myGlobalSMSPro.getGlobalSMSProSoap();
        java.lang.String methodName = null;
        sms.com.strikeiron.ws.LicenseInfo licenseInfo = null;
        smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder subscriptionInfo = new  smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder();
        subscriptionInfo.value = null;
        port.getStatusCodesForMethod(methodName, licenseInfo, subscriptionInfo);
    }

    public void testGlobalSMSProSoapgetStatusCodes() throws java.lang.Exception {
        smsgateway.GlobalSMSProSoap port = myGlobalSMSPro.getGlobalSMSProSoap();
        sms.com.strikeiron.ws.LicenseInfo licenseInfo = null;
        smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder subscriptionInfo = new  smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder();
        subscriptionInfo.value = null;
        port.getStatusCodes(licenseInfo, subscriptionInfo);
    }

    public void testGlobalSMSProSoapgetServiceInfo() throws java.lang.Exception {
        smsgateway.GlobalSMSProSoap port = myGlobalSMSPro.getGlobalSMSProSoap();
        sms.com.strikeiron.ws.LicenseInfo licenseInfo = null;
        smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder subscriptionInfo = new  smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder();
        subscriptionInfo.value = null;
        port.getServiceInfo(licenseInfo, subscriptionInfo);
    }

    public void testGlobalSMSProSoapgetRemainingHits() throws java.lang.Exception {
        smsgateway.GlobalSMSProSoap port = myGlobalSMSPro.getGlobalSMSProSoap();
        sms.com.strikeiron.ws.LicenseInfo licenseInfo = null;
        smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder subscriptionInfo = new  smsgateway.holders.SubscriptionInfoHolder();
        subscriptionInfo.value = null;
        port.getRemainingHits(licenseInfo, subscriptionInfo);
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you try to remove public constructor from your test class?

Comment: I remove public constructor. But still same error...

Comment: Can you clarify the question with full stacktrace?